# How do I find hostels where I can safely store my documents while leaving the room?

Tags: accommodation, security, hostels

We are going to watch some games in Euro 2016 France, and we want to book some hostels. apparently it is expensive to have a room for two so we want to share a bed in a doorm but we don't know the other people so we can't put the passports in the room, so they told me that i can put our passports in the hostel, but they also said not all hostels support this feature.

please what is the name of this feature so i can search on booking.com or trip advisor for hostels have it

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "we can't put the passports in the room"?  Do you mean some kind of safety box to store your valuables?

Comment: @jpatokal yes, how can i leave my passport in the room with strangers ?, there should be this safetly box in the hostel where we leave our passports and go arround the city

Comment: I can not find hard proof right now, but as far as I can see you have to carry your passport with you as foreigner in France. It is always suggested by some countries. Just make sure you hide it well under your clothes. Leaving it in a hotel or hostel room, in a good safe or locker might be acceptable but I have never trusted any of those. I would certainly not leave it in a hotel room if it is not in a safe.

Comment: I would also recommend to always have some ID with you, because of the rather tense context due to the recent terrorist attacks. As stated on this site (unfortunately not translated in english) https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F1036 , if you can not show a valid ID during a routine check, you may have to go to a police station for up to 4 hours.

Answer (score 17):

This "feature" is called a "Security locker" or "In-room safe" (the latter usually being available in proper hotels, not hostels). You can filter based on that parameter on Hostelworld, for example:

[image: hostelworld search]

Usually the lockers will look something like this:

[image: hostel locker]

They're divided into several types, ranging in their level of security:

1. In-room safes, a metal box built into the wall, usually opened using a pin-code. These are rare in hostels as they're quite bulky.
2. Pin-code/security card based lockers. You see the same kind of lockers in many spa resorts and pools - the door locks and opens using your own room key or a pin code that you set before closing the door.
3. Lockers secured with a hanging lock. These usually require you to bring your own lock or rent one from the hostel.
4. "Ask the receptionist" locker, where you store whatever valuables you have with the hostel's reception. They usually have a single safe for everyone's valuables.
5. And finally, the "under bed cage", which is just a metal box placed under the bed. These offer the least amount of security as they're usually poorly secured and their contents are visible.

I would recommend getting your own padlock before visiting a hostel - they're rarely more than a few euros at any lock store. This will save you considerable head-ache if you run into a hostel where a hanging lock is needed.

Answer (score 5):

The word you are looking for is likely Locker.

This is fairly common in most hostels and might not be announced on some booking sites.
When the site does not mention lockers at all, you should use or double check with an other search site or look on the site of the hostel.
Or call the hostel and check whether they do offer the service.
I can not remember the last hostel that did not supply a way to secure items, but I must also say that I do not use the cheapest hostels.

Basically lockers are cupboards with locks or a secure place to use your own pad lock. 
When pad locks are used, the hostels normally rents them out but carrying your own is easy.

Lockers can be just big enough for a daypack, but many are big enough that a mid-sized suitcase or a mid-sized backpack fits in.

Besides, many hostels accept valuables handed in at the front desk.